# Regular expression pattern for validating amount

Tags: regex, wildcard

Please help me with the regex pattern to validate amount.
Conditions:

1. The fist character can be -(to indicate negative amount) or $ or any number between 1-9
2. consecutive characters may contain (,)comma,(.)decimal point

Example

```
- 1.122 - Valid
-1.22 - Valid
-$1.22 - Valid</b>
-$20,000.22 - Valid

-$20,000.22 - Valid
20.00-1 - invalid
-20.00-1 - invalid
-$20.00-1 - invalid
-20.00*1 - invalid
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
/^[-+]?\$? *\d+(,\d{3})*(\.\d+)?$/gm
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gA0hG3/1)